# apt dist-upgrade and Discovery giving different update information

Tags: apt, gnome, 18.10, plasma

I am running Ubuntu 18.10 (installed from mini iso) with Plasma desktop 5.13.5 (from the repositories.)  I always do updates on the command line without any issues.  sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade shows that there are no updates, yet Discovery shows there is an update
"GNOME Application Platform version 3.32".  I have not taken this update.

The Discovery icon always shows 1 update pending, but sometimes when I open Discovery it says there are no updates.  This GNOME update seems to come and go but still, apt never sees it.

How can I figure out what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue between flatpak and Discovery.  I did

```
flatpak update
```

It showed there were updates (didn't mention the GNOME 3.32 one by name.)  I took those and the Discovery icon and its listed update went away.  I don't understand the reason behind this.  I though flatpaks updated themselves when you ran a flatpak program and I have been doing that.